# Looking for good Billing Platforms to integrate with my Web Application(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, in-app-billing, braintree, recurring-billing

I am looking for a billing platform that I can integrate into my Web Application(MVC).

**Tried**: `PayPal` and `Braintree`

`PayPal`: They dont seem to support South Africa.

`BrainTree`: I got a Sandbox working, test transactions work well and could change to ZAR, but their FAQ states the countries you need to live in to use Braintree and South Africa doesnt fall in any of them.

**Tried**: I have contacted a local company that has come sort of billing platform, but no one is replying...typical.

**Looking for**: I am looking for a billing platform that I can integrate into my Web Application that I can use running from South Africa, and later international traffic, that can allow one or all of the following: Once-off Credit card Debits, monthly recurring debits, debits allowed via bank details.

I appreciate any help in the right direction..

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to down vote, please at least give a reason why, so that I can fix my question.

Comment: When you create your Q at the right side you should see something like that: Is your question about programming?

We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

Provide details. Share your research.

If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that there was another part allowing for questions. I will try and figure it out. But if you have a list of billing platforms that you are aware of, please share and I shall mark that as the answer. This is all new to me, so I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (and note item 4)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, that does actually make sense. Ive just been searching for so long and have not found a solution and Stack Overflow was the only place where I could think of getting help. But will admit that I have noticed that people give more negative comments than positive help. Its sad that people will more often, easily downvote than try help - that is ultimately why we all registered here is it not.... But thanks for the link, it is and will be helpful with further questions, if I decide to carry on using this platform. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a billing platform that seems will work : PayGate.

Regarding stack overflow, I have been very disappointed with how this forum operates and will no longer make use of it. Posting questions gets more negative comments than people actually helping, which is very unfortunate. I have asked some questions in a manner that is not always 100% correct, but I have tried many different ways of asking my questions and followed others recommendations, but the result is always the same. Take this question as an example - Sure, the question might not have fitted the standard 100%, but not one comment that was made was to try help with my actual question, but rather on how wrong I asked it. Guys, this isnt how it is supposed to be. In any case, I will most probably also receive harsh and negative feedback for this, but, that will just prove my point even more. Good luck to those who are seeking help on this forum. Cheers